# The 'Pods-Runner' target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries

Tags: ios, flutter, agora.io

Here's Flutter and Xcode versions:

```
Flutter 1.22.5 • channel stable 
Version 12.3 (12C33)
```

I have a Flutter application and I get the following error when trying to install the pods:

The error message was about AgoraRtcEngine, previously I was using agora 3.2.1 and the error message complained that I need 3.3.1 and then I upgraded it.

Then I try to install all the dependencies, unfortunately, I got the `The 'Pods-Runner' target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries` error.

I tried below commands but failed with the attached error:

1. flutter clean
2. remove ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
3. remove PodFile and PodFile.lock
4. flutter build ios

Does anyone know what is the cause and how to solve it? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to update CocoaPods, what version are you currently using

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7234#issuecomment-346119807

follow the instructions that are given in terminal output:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

you might wanna upgrade your CocoaPods and also your flutter version

upgrading your installing CocoaPods -> "sudo gem install cocoapods"

this will take a while or throw error, incase of error try manually downloading cocoapods from web " https://cocoapods.org/app " this will download a dmg application file.

and for flutter

try "flutter upgrade"